# Fehler bei B2-Vorbereitung Test

Tags: meaning, article, possessive-pronoun

Ich möchte mich für die B2-Prüfung beim Goethe Institut anmelden und deshalb habe ich neulich ein Buch gekauft, damit ich mich darin üben kann.

Gestern sollte ich die folgende Übung lösen. Es handelt sich um einen Brief, den ich korrigieren soll. Ich habe ein paar Zweifel und bin ich nicht einverstanden mit den Lösungen.

[image: "Mit Erfolg zum Goethe-Zertifikat B2"]

Also, meiner Meinung nach ist die richtige Antwort für Zeile 17 **der** (weder *die* noch *den*). Außerdem habe ich in Zeile 20 **meiner** geschrieben: Ist das richtig?

Ich habe auch eine andere Frage: Was bedeutet "Auf den Nachttisch ... verzichten"?

Ich bin auch ein bisschen verdutzt über den Schluss: Ich bin ganz sicher dass **Mit freundlichen Grüßen** eigentlich richtig ist, aber die offizielle Lösung ist im Singular...

Comment: Woher kommen die Lösungen?

Comment: Ja danke, ich meinte (17). Herzliche Dank für Ihre Rückmeldung, ich war ganz unruhig darüber. Leider kommen die Lösungen direkt aus dem Buch... Danke vielmals!

Comment: Ich hatte zwei Kommentare gelesen aber jetzt ist ein spurlos verschwunden :(

Comment: Es tut mir leid, aber ich kann mir wirklich nicht vorstellen, daß die Lösungen aus dem Buch kommen, das wäre ein ziemlicher Skandal. Welches Buch ist das genau? Können Sie ein Foto von der Vorderseite und der Lösungsseite machen?

Comment: Die Kommentare waren hinfällig, die Frage wurde schon korrigiert, tut mir leid für die Verwirrung.

Comment: Hier ist das Buch: https://www.amazon.de/Mit-Erfolg-zum-Goethe-Zertifikat-%C3%9Cbungsbuch/dp/3126758304 und das Bild, das ich gepostet habe, kommt direkt aus der Lösungsseite... es tut mir auch leid und ich bedanke mich bei Ihnen für Ihre Hilfe.

Comment: @Thomas: Wenn Du schon dabei bist, nimm doch bitte dann auch die Grüße immer raus. Konvention ist hier: Keine Begrüßungsfloskeln, keine Abschiedsfloskeln, keine Dankesfloskeln. Danke.

Comment: @userunknown Nö, das wäre unpassend.

Comment: @Romeo Wo haben Sie das Buch denn gekauft?

Comment: @Thomas: Please see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989

Comment: Für mich gehörte sie zum Kontext des Fragenden...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was based on obvious errors in a text book that could not be reproduced. It is unlikely to help future visitors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Die Korrektur 17 ist falsch, es muss **der** heißen.
Die Korrektur 20 ist ebenfalls falsch, es muss **meiner** heißen.
Der Rest passt so. Außer dass es nicht *Zeile* heißen sollte, sondern *Fehler* und die Numerierung ist auch Mist.

*Mit freundlichem Gruß* ist nicht ganz so üblich wie *Mit freundlichen Grüßen*, aber korrekt. Prinzipiell kann man da natürlich auch *Ohne Gruß* oder *Mit schlimmen Verwünschungen* schreiben. Das wäre eine ganz passende Formel für einen Beschwerdebrief an den Lektor dieses Machwerks.

Comment: Achtung mit den Witzen, ich glaube das versteht der OP nicht. Vlt. sollte man noch Hochachtungsvoll erwähnen. ;-)

Comment: Nachttisch ist auch falsch. BTW

Comment: Wollte ich auch gerade schreiben.

Comment: Nein, *Nachtisch* ist die *Nachspeise*. Eis, Tiramisu, Pannacotta oder sowas. Wer weiß, was damit gewesen wäre. Ein *Nach**t**tisch* ist hingegen ein kleiner Tisch neben dem Bett.

Comment: Es passt nicht mit *dankend verzichten*. Man kann *auf das Trinkgeldgeben verzichten*, und das dann *auf das Trinkgeld verzichten* verkürzen, das wird aus dem Zusammenhang schon richtig verstanden.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G6D1YI-41ao

Answer (score 2):

> Was bedeutet "Auf den Nachttisch ... verzichten"?

Es bedeutet, dass die Personen keinen Nachtisch bestellt haben, sondern gleich nach der Hauptspeise das Restaurant verließen.

Comment: Plus it’s „Nachtisch”, not „Nachttisch“. (dessert vs. night table)

Answer (score 1):

Wen auch immer es interessiert, das rezitierte Buch scheint es so nicht (mehr) zu geben. Ein Auszug bei Amazon sieht wie folgt aus. Dort sind keine Fehler zu finden.

[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21324)

Comment: @tofro Bitte beteilige dich an der Diskussion im Chat-Raum, wenn du Fragen zu diesem Post hast.

Comment: @tofro hat keine Fragen. Er sagt dir (mit Recht), dass dein "Post" keine Antwort ist, sondern höchstens ein Kommentar.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Die Frage hat das schwerwiegende Probleme mit zweifelhaften Quellen zu arbeiten, deshalb wurde sie mittlerweile geschlossen. Zum Zwecke der Aufklärung habe ich das hier geposted. Die Hintergründe sind im Chat zu finden.

Comment: Posten ist gut, aber **nicht als Antwort**. Das sollte als Link in einem Kommentar gepostet werden, egal welche Hintergründe das hat.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Kann den Standpunkt verstehen, teile ihn aber nicht vollständig. Ich sah die Notwendigkeit, das hier prominent klar zu machen. Manchmal müssen Strukturen halt aufgebrochen werden.

Comment: @Thomas: Dafür gibt es klare Regeln. SE lässt da keine Ausnahmen (mehr) zu.

Answer (score -3):

> Was bedeutet "Auf den Nachttisch ... verzichten"?

Es bedeutet, dass die Personen keinen Nachttisch vom unfreundlichen Kellner übergezogen haben wollten.

Comment: Finde die "Downvotes" ziemlich übertrieben. War einigemaßen witzig, obwohl wahrscheinlich ziemlich irreführend, wenn OP nicht weiß, was der Unterschied zwischen Nachtisch und Nachttisch ist.

Comment: @Rudy Velhus, das sehe ich genauso, zumal die gleiche Antwort, aber von jemand anderem geschrieben, positiv bewertet wurde.